# JSON value with std::variant

Tags: c++, json, c++17

For learning purposes, I wanted to implement a class that could hold JSON data with std::variant. Most of the implementations I found online were using incomplete types as template arguments for map, which is -at least according to my understanding- not C++17 compliant and implementation dependant (sometimes [not compiling](https://godbolt.org/z/Ga548G8ca)).

Instead, I used a recursive wrapper with `std::unique_ptr` to bypass this limitation.

I plan to add a parser/serializer and more features like iterators to make it more useful (with the same kind of interface as excellent [Nlohmann's library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)). But before going further, I'd like to know if there is a massive flaw in my design. I am also interested in any optimizations I could make to prevent extra copies for example.

**json.hpp**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

namespace Json {
  namespace Internal {
    template<typename T>
    class RecursiveWrapper {
    public:
      RecursiveWrapper(const RecursiveWrapper& r) : p(std::make_unique<T>(*r.p)) {}
      RecursiveWrapper(RecursiveWrapper&& r) noexcept : p(std::move(r.p)) {}
      RecursiveWrapper(const T& r) : p(std::make_unique<T>(r)) {}
      ~RecursiveWrapper() = default;

      operator const T& () const { return *p.get(); }
      operator T& () { return *p.get(); }

      RecursiveWrapper& operator=(const RecursiveWrapper& other) {
        if (other.p)
          p = std::make_unique<T>(*other.p);
        else
          p.reset();

        return *this;
      }

    private:
      std::unique_ptr<T> p;
    };
  }

  class Array;
  class Object;

  using Value = std::variant<
    std::monostate,
    Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Object>,
    Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Array>,
    std::string,
    bool,
    long long int,
    double
  >;

  class Json : protected Value {
    using Value::Value;
  public:
    Json(std::nullptr_t = nullptr);
    Json(std::initializer_list<Json> init);
    Json(const char* s); // prevent "string" to be casted to bool

    template<
      typename T,
      std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<T, Value> && !std::is_same_v<T, bool>&& std::is_integral_v<T>, bool> = true
    >
      Json(const T i) : Value(static_cast<long long int>(i)) { } // Cast other int types to long long int

    template<typename T>
    const T& get() const {
      if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void>)
        throw std::runtime_error("Json value is empty");
      else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Object>)
        return static_cast<const Object&>(std::get<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Object>>(*this));
      else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Array>)
        return static_cast<const Array&>(std::get<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Array>>(*this));
      else
        return std::get<T>(static_cast<const Value&>(*this));
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& get() {
      if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void>)
        throw std::runtime_error("Json value is empty");
      else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Object>)
        return static_cast<Object&>(std::get<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Object>>(*this));
      else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Array>)
        return static_cast<Array&>(std::get<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Array>>(*this));
      else
        return std::get<T>(static_cast<Value&>(*this));
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool is() const {
      if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Object>)
        return std::holds_alternative<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Object>>(*this);
      else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Array>)
        return std::holds_alternative<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Array>>(*this);
      else
        return std::holds_alternative<T>(*this);
    }

    Json& operator[](const std::string& s);
    const Json& operator[](const std::string& s) const;

    Json& operator[](const size_t i);
    const Json& operator[](const size_t i) const;
  };

  class Array : public std::vector<Json> { using std::vector<Json>::vector; };
  class Object : public std::unordered_map<std::string, Json> { using std::unordered_map<std::string, Json>::unordered_map; };
}
```

**json.cpp**

```cpp
#include "json.hpp"
namespace Json {
Value JsonFromInitList(std::initializer_list<Json> init) {
    if (init.size() == 2 && init.begin()->is<std::string>())
      return Object({ { init.begin()->get<std::string>(), *(init.begin() + 1) } });

    // If all elements are pairs and first element is a string,
    // this is an object, otherwise it's an array
    for (const auto& j : init) {
      if (!j.is<Object>() || j.get<Object>().size() != 1)
        return Array(init);
    }

    Object output;
    for (const auto& j : init) {
      output.insert(*j.get<Object>().begin());
    }
    return output;
  }

  Json::Json(std::nullptr_t) { }
  Json::Json(std::initializer_list<Json> init) : Value(JsonFromInitList(init)) { }
  Json::Json(const char* s) : Value(std::string(s)) { }

  Json& Json::operator[](const std::string& s) {
    // If empty, convert it to object
    if (std::holds_alternative<std::monostate>(*this))
      *this = Object();
    if (!std::holds_alternative<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Object>>(*this))
      throw std::runtime_error("Json value is not an object");

    return get<Object>()[s];
  }

  const Json& Json::operator[](const std::string& s) const {
    if (!std::holds_alternative<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Object>>(*this))
      throw std::runtime_error("Json value is not an object");

    return get<Object>().at(s);
  }

  Json& Json::operator[](const size_t i) {
    if (!std::holds_alternative<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Array>>(*this))
      throw std::runtime_error("Json value is not an array");

    return get<Array>()[i];
  }

  const Json& Json::operator[](const size_t i) const {
    if (!std::holds_alternative<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Array>>(*this))
      throw std::runtime_error("Json value is not an array");

    return get<Array>().at(i);
  }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <cassert>

#include "json.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const Json::Json json =
  {
    {"pi", 3.141},
    {"happy", true},
    {"nothing", nullptr},
    {
      "answer", {
        {"everything", 42}
      }
    },
    {"list", {1, 0, 2}},
    {
      "object", {
        {"currency", "USD"},
        {"value", 42.99}
      }
    }
  };

  assert(json.is<Json::Object>());
  assert(json.get<Json::Object>().size() == 6);
  assert(json["happy"].is<bool>());
  assert(json["nothing"].is<std::monostate>());
  assert(json["answer"].is<Json::Object>());
  assert(json["answer"].get<Json::Object>().size() == 1);
  assert(json["answer"]["everything"].is<long long int>());
  assert(json["answer"]["everything"].get<long long int>() == 42);
  assert(json["list"].is<Json::Array>());
  assert(json["list"].get<Json::Array>().size() == 3);
  assert(json["list"][2].get<long long int>() == 2);
  assert(json["object"].is<Json::Object>());
  assert(json["object"].get<Json::Object>().size() == 2);

  Json::Json json2 = {};
  assert(json2.is<std::monostate>());
  json2["key"] = json;
  assert(json2.is<Json::Object>());
  assert(json2["key"].is<Json::Object>());
  const Json::Json json3 = "Hello";
  assert(json3.is<std::string>());
  assert(json3.get<std::string>() == "Hello");
  const Json::Json json4 = 3.5f;
  assert(json4.is<double>());

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  RecursiveWrapper(const RecursiveWrapper& r) : p(std::make_unique<T>(*r.p)) {}
> ```

Might be dereferencing a null ptr?

---

> ```
>   RecursiveWrapper(const T& r) : p(std::make_unique<T>(r)) {}
> ```

Should be `explicit` to prevent accidents.

We probably want a move version too: `RecursiveWrapper(T&& r) p(std::make_unique<T>(std::move(r))) {}`

---

> ```
>   operator const T& () const { return *p.get(); }
>   operator T& () { return *p.get(); }
> ```

It would be safer to provide `get()` functions instead of implicit (!!) conversion operators (!).

Again, we might be dereferencing a null ptr. We could add an `assert` to clearly indicate that we're aware of the issue, and that it's the caller's responsibility to avoid it.

---

> ```
> class Json : protected Value {
>   using Value::Value;
> ```

I think there are more downsides than upsides to inheriting from `std::variant` (and most other std types). Especially here, where we don't actually want any of the functionality to be public. It's much simpler to use an ordinary member variable.

---

> ```
> Json(std::nullptr_t = nullptr);
> Json(std::initializer_list<Json> init);
> Json(const char* s); // prevent "string" to be casted to bool
>
> template<
>   typename T,
>   std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<T, Value> && !std::is_same_v<T, bool> && std::is_integral_v<T>, bool> = true
> >
>   Json(const T i) : Value(static_cast<long long int>(i)) { } // Cast other int types to long long int
> ```

You'll need a lot of testing with various different types to make sure there aren't any unexpected conversions due to the implicit constructors here. Inheriting from std::variant makes this especially (and unnecessarily?) complicated.

I'm actually a bit suprised that a `Json` can be constructed from a `bool` or `double`. (How? Maybe that's worth a comment in the code if it's intentional).

---

> ```
>   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void>)
>     throw std::runtime_error("Json value is empty");
> ```

Perhaps we should make this a compile time error instead of a runtime error?

> ```
>   else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Object>)
>     return static_cast<const Object&>(std::get<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Object>>(*this));
>   else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Array>)
>     return static_cast<const Array&>(std::get<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Array>>(*this));
>   else
>     return std::get<T>(static_cast<const Value&>(*this));
> ```

`std::get` will throw a `std::bad_variant_access` if we get the type wrong, but I'm not sure we want to expose the user to `std::variant`. We might check the type ourselves, and throw a `std::runtime_error` with a more useful message instead.

---

> ```
> Json& operator[](const std::string& s);
> const Json& operator[](const std::string& s) const;
>
> Json& operator[](const size_t i);
> const Json& operator[](const size_t i) const;
> ```

Hmmmmmmmmmm... If you start down this route, you'll probably end up providing the entire `map` and `vector` interfaces in the `Json` object. For example, what use is `operator[]` without being able to call `.size()`? And then we should provide iterator access, right? And why only provide the interfaces for arrays and maps, when we could allow the user to use `operator+` directly on integer values?! etc. It's a rather deep rabbit hole.

It might be more verbose to make the user write `j.get<Array>()[0]` instead of `j[0]`, but that may prove simpler and easier (for both you and the user) in the long run.

---

> ```
> class Array : public std::vector<Json> { using std::vector<Json>::vector; };
> class Object : public std::unordered_map<std::string, Json> { using std::unordered_map<std::string, Json>::unordered_map; };
> ```

Can these not be simple typedefs? I think we can do all that with forward declaration:

```
class Json;
using Array = std::vector<Json>;
using Object = std::unordered_map<Json>;

class Json {
    
    ...
    
    using Value = std::variant<..., Array, Object>;
    Value value;
};
```

The `Value` typedef and all the variant shenanigans can then be neatly hidden inside `Json`, and not something the user has to care about.

---

> ```
> Value JsonFromInitList(std::initializer_list<Json> init) {
> if (init.size() == 2 && init.begin()->is<std::string>())
>   return Object({ { init.begin()->get<std::string>(), *(init.begin() + 1) } });
>
> // If all elements are pairs and first element is a string,
> // this is an object, otherwise it's an array
> for (const auto& j : init) {
>   if (!j.is<Object>() || j.get<Object>().size() != 1)
>     return Array(init);
> }
>
> Object output;
> for (const auto& j : init) {
>   output.insert(*j.get<Object>().begin());
> }
> return output;
> ```
>
> }

I don't think this is correct (or at least, there are lots of ambiguities), e.g.:

- Are 2 strings really always an object, never an array?
- Why can't we have an array of pairs, where the first value of each pair is a string?

We probably need separate `Array` and `Object` constructors for `Json` instead of a single `initializer_list` constructor.

(And I don't think there's any reasonable way to avoid putting the burden of specifying `Array` / `Object` types on the user, but I also don't think that's a problem. We can't use `[]` and `{}` to differentiate arrays and objects in C++ code).

So, for example:

```
  const Json::Json json =
  Json::Object {
    {"pi", 3.141}, // we're initializing a std::map<string, variant> now, so this shouldn't need the type specified
    {"happy", true},
    {"nothing", nullptr},
    {
      "answer", Json::Object{ // specify the type
        {"everything", 42}
      }
    },
    {"list", Json::Array{1, 0, 2}}, // specify the type
    {
      "object", Json::Object{ // specify the type
        {"currency", "USD"},
        {"value", 42.99}
      }
    }
  };
```

---

> ```
> Json& Json::operator[](const std::string& s) {
> // If empty, convert it to object
> if (std::holds_alternative<std::monostate>(*this))
>   *this = Object();
> if (!std::holds_alternative<Internal::RecursiveWrapper<Object>>(*this))
>   throw std::runtime_error("Json value is not an object");
>
> return get<Object>()[s];
> ```
>
> }

Ehhhhhhh... That cast to `Object` seems kinda sus. I'm not sure a "null" should be treated the same way as an "empty Object" in JSON (and why not as an empty Array instead / too?). If the user wanted an empty "Object", they could have created one. If they go to the bother of explicitly creating a null value, then they probably want the type safety to go with it.

(Which maybe indicates that we shouldn't actually *have* a default constructor for the `Json` class, because we need the user to specify the type).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed review. For your typedef suggestion, you can't use incomplete types (like Json here) in STL containers (with a very few exceptions, but not map and unordered_map, see [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Gzh5n6rbn)). About the operator[] and initializer_list, I'm trying to have something close to Nlohmann's json library interface which I'm used to work with. Of course it comes with some limitations, but these features are very handy to have.